# Java: Detecting client disconnects from server side

Tags: java, sockets, client, client-server

I am writing a Java client/server program using Socket and ServerSocket. Multiple clients connect to the server at once. What is the best way to check if a client connection has disconnected from the server side? Right now, I'm just getting a SocketException when attempting to write to a disconnected client.

Comment: this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698964/checking-if-a-clientsocket-has-disconnected-in-java-hangs

Comment: The `SocketException` tells you that *you* have *already* closed the socket. It indicates a logic bug in your application. The way to *detect* a closed connection, rather than ignoring it as you are now, is by `read()` returning -1 or `write()` throwing an `IOException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to detect a disconnection is to have the other end send a heartbeat and have the reader timeout when there is no data.

Comment: Just to clarify, who would be sending the heartbeats? The server or the clients?

Comment: The writer sends the heartbeats, the reader expects them. It doesn't matter which end is the client or server.

Comment: @PeterLawrey how can we assume there is a proper disconnect from the client end to apply heartbeat call... there might be an interruption that breaks socket connection... I would want to detect and do change appropriate change for particular user.

Comment: @Sathish You detect it by the hearbeat write failing, or not being received.