# Checking if client still connected

Tags: java, tcp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Detecting client disconnects from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606947/java-detecting-client-disconnects-from-server-side)

What is the best way to check if a client is still connected to the server? Tell me exactly how the method you're suggesting works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the client to send a heartbeat message. When no message has been received for a given length, the client can be disconnected.

Answer (score -1):

> > what type of class for your client?If you use socket, there is a function isConnected() you can try!

Comment: Not correct. Does not tell you whether the peer has disconnected.