# Detecting a broken socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ip

I'm working with TCP IP Socket.

Is [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698964/checking-if-a-clientsocket-has-disconnected-in-java-hangs) the simplest way to detect that a client socket connection is broken?

I would be surprised if there is no Java API that detects a dead client and throws an exception. This should be possible at least when the server tries to send a packet to the client from the lack of an ACK response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP protocol does not support any fast means of detecting a broken connection.

This question (and all of it's answers) explain the problem in full: [Does a TCP socket connection have a "keep alive"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480236/does-a-tcp-socket-connection-have-a-keep-alive)

So basically yes, that is the simplest way. You need to implement ping-pong packets (aka HearBeat packet) in your application protocol to verify the broken connection properly.