# how I will use setsockopt and getsockopt with KEEP_ALIVE in linux c programming to determine broken tcp/ip connection?

Tags: c, linux, tcp

how I will use setsockopt and getsockopt in linux c programming to determine broken tcp/ip connection?

Answer (score 6):

From the [TCP man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp):

> To set or get a TCP socket option, call `getsockopt(2)` to read or `setsockopt(2)` to write the option with the option level argument set to `IPPROTO_TCP`.

Here are the relevant options:

`TCP_KEEPCNT` (since Linux 2.4)

> The maximum number of keepalive probes TCP should send before dropping the connection. This option should not be used in code intended to be portable.

`TCP_KEEPIDLE` (since Linux 2.4)

> The time (in seconds) the connection needs to remain idle before TCP starts sending keepalive probes, if the socket option SO_KEEPALIVE has been set on this socket. This option should not be used in code intended to be portable.

`TCP_KEEPINTVL` (since Linux 2.4)

> The time (in seconds) between individual keepalive probes. This option should not be used in code intended to be portable.

Example:

```
int keepcnt = 5;
int keepidle = 30;
int keepintvl = 120;

setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &keepcnt, sizeof(int));
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &keepidle, sizeof(int));
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &keepintvl, sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the socket option SO_KEEPALIVE might helps. Code from APUE:

```
int keepalive = 1;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &keepalive , sizeof(keepalive ));
```

And reference this: [Detecting a broken socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507023/detecting-a-broken-socket)

Comment: Did you copy that from an example for `SO_REUSEADDR`? The name `reuse` looks weird.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Thanks for pointing out that. I got the code from APUE. I've edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

As @luly and @jxh answered, Firstly, you need enable keep-alive by setting SO_KEEPALIVE. Then control the **interval of normal heartbeat** using TCP_KEEPIDLE, **interval of abnormal (unacknowledged) heartbeats** using TCP_KEEPINTVL, and **threshold of abnormal heartbeats** using TCP_KEEPCNT.

For the purpose of detecting a broken connection, those options need to be set from the **server-side**.

A detailed explanation can be found from [here](https://holmeshe.me/network-essentials-setsockopt-SO_KEEPALIVE/)